# How to use jQuery and jQuery plugins with PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

I've a PrimeFaces web application. When I manually add jQuery and plugins like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/onebyone/jquery.onebyone.js"></script>              
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/onebyone/jquery.touchwipe.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-5.5.0.js"></script>
```

then PrimeFaces components loose their functionality and some of their styles. For example, `<p:dialog>` don't show up, `<p:accordionPanel>` doesn't slide, `<p:panelGrid>` loses padding, etcetera.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

PrimeFaces already ships with jQuery bundled, yet you've downloaded and installed another one which would only conflict with PrimeFaces bundled jQuery. I'm sure that if you have paid a bit more attention and love to the webbrowser's builtin JavaScript console, you would have seen JS errors. And, if you checked the JSF-generated HTML output via rightclick, *View Source* in webbrowser, you would have seen another `jquery.js` file being included in HTML `<head>`.

You need to **remove** the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

In case you have pages which do not necessarily use PrimeFaces components, and thus its jQuery wouldn't automatically be included, then you'd need to explicitly load its bundled jQuery by a proper `<h:outputScript>`.

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
```

Note that using `<h:outputScript>` does not end up in a duplicate script include on pages which actually use PrimeFaces components.

#### See also:

- [Adding jQuery to PrimeFaces results in Uncaught TypeError over all place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/adding-jquery-to-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerror-over-all-place)
- [How to solve a conflict with primefaces jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508564/how-to-solve-a-conflict-with-primefaces-jquery/)

Comment: thank you, you saved me from a lot of trouble. Need to get a bit deeper into javascript

Comment: After testing the application for a little longer I found out that there are still issues or conflicts between jquery and ajax of primefaces

Comment: jQuery and Ajax of PrimeFaces conflicts are unlikely because Ajax and all the widgets of PrimeFaces are implemented with jQuery :)

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail. What errors exactly do you get?

Comment: Saying that `<h:outputScript>` does not duplicate the script, would this be considered bad practice or harmful to include `jquery/jquery.js` in template to have it available in all pages (some not having primefaces components).

Comment: @BalusC I'm using primefaces jquery with the same way, but I have an issue with IE ('$' is undefined). could you help me

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2:** I ran a manual debug and found out that this line was causing the trouble, and after removing it, things got back to normal hopefully.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

I wasn't actually getting any errors or excretions but some primeface components were acting weird. For example I have a `selectOneMenu` component defined with a converter. When one item is selected the form gets updated via Ajax. The problem was after selecting an item the menu items got broken (they were representing numbers instead of text) as if somehow the converter wasn't working and the other commands of the page stooped functioning (were not doing anything).

Another problem was `datatable` component where each row has a commandlink which triggers some Ajax behavior. After the links are clicked the pagination of datatable wasn't working.

From these issues I assumed that there is a conflict between jQuery and ajax.

Although its a very large file, If anyone is interested this is the content of the js file that was causing the troubles

```
 (function($) {
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.accordion li').click(function () {
        $(this).each(function() {
            $('ul.accordion li').removeClass('active');
            });
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('ul.accordion').accordion({
        active: ".active",
        autoHeight: false,
        header: ".opener",
        collapsible: true,
        event: "click"
    });
});
});
})(jQuery);

// background resize init
function initBackgroundResize() {
var holder = document.getElementById('bg');
if(holder) {
    var images = holder.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        BackgroundStretcher.stretchImage(images[i]);
    }
    BackgroundStretcher.setBgHolder(holder);
}
 }

 if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", initBackgroundResize, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", initBackgroundResize);

 // image stretch module
 BackgroundStretcher = {
images: [],
holders: [],
viewWidth: 0,
viewHeight: 0,
ieFastMode: true,
stretchBy: 'window', // "window", "page", "block-id", or block
init: function(){
    this.addHandlers();
    this.resizeAll();
    return this;
},
stretchImage: function(origImg) {
    // wrap image and apply smoothing
    var obj = this.prepareImage(origImg);

    // handle onload
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = this.bind(function(){
        obj.iRatio = img.width / img.height;
        this.resizeImage(obj);
    });
    img.src = origImg.src;
    this.images.push(obj);
},
prepareImage: function(img) {
    var wrapper = document.createElement('span');
    img.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, img);
    wrapper.appendChild(img);

    if(/MSIE (6|7|8)/.test(navigator.userAgent) && img.tagName.toLowerCase()  === 'img') {
        wrapper.style.position = 'absolute';
        wrapper.style.display = 'block';
        wrapper.style.zoom = 1;
        if(this.ieFastMode) {
            img.style.display = 'none';
            wrapper.style.filter =  'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="'+img.src+'",  sizingMethod="scale")'; // enable smoothing in IE6
            return wrapper;
        } else {
            img.style.msInterpolationMode = 'bicubic'; // IE7 smooth  fix
            return img;
        }
    } else {
        return img;
    }
},
setBgHolder: function(obj) {
    this.holders.push(obj);
    this.resizeAll();
},
resizeImage: function(obj) {
    if(obj.iRatio) {
        // calculate dimensions
        var dimensions = this.getProportion({
            ratio: obj.iRatio,
            maskWidth: this.viewWidth,
            maskHeight: this.viewHeight
        });
        // apply new styles
        obj.style.width = dimensions.width + 'px';
        obj.style.height = dimensions.height + 'px';
        obj.style.top = dimensions.top + 'px';
        obj.style.left = dimensions.left +'px';
    }
},
resizeHolder: function(obj) {
    obj.style.width = this.viewWidth+'px';
    obj.style.height = this.viewHeight+'px';
},
getProportion: function(data) {
    // calculate element coords to fit in mask
    var ratio = data.ratio || (data.elementWidth / data.elementHeight);
    var slideWidth = data.maskWidth, slideHeight = slideWidth / ratio;
    if(slideHeight < data.maskHeight) {
        slideHeight = data.maskHeight;
        slideWidth = slideHeight * ratio;
    }
    return {
        width: slideWidth,
        height: slideHeight,
        top: (data.maskHeight - slideHeight) / 2,
        left: (data.maskWidth - slideWidth) / 2
    }
},
resizeAll: function() {
    // crop holder width by window size
    for(var i = 0; i < this.holders.length; i++) {
        this.holders[i].style.width = '100%'; 
    }

    // delay required for IE to handle resize
    clearTimeout(this.resizeTimer);
    this.resizeTimer = setTimeout(this.bind(function(){
        // hide background holders
        for(var i = 0; i < this.holders.length; i++) {
            this.holders[i].style.display = 'none';
        }

        // calculate real page dimensions with hidden background blocks
        if(typeof this.stretchBy === 'string') {
            // resize by window or page dimensions
            if(this.stretchBy === 'window' || this.stretchBy === 'page') {
                this.viewWidth =  this.stretchFunctions[this.stretchBy].width();
                this.viewHeight = this.stretchFunctions[this.stretchBy].height();
            }
            // resize by element dimensions (by id)
            else {
                var maskObject = document.getElementById(this.stretchBy);
                this.viewWidth = maskObject ? maskObject.offsetWidth : 0;
                this.viewHeight = maskObject ? maskObject.offsetHeight : 0;
            }
        } else {
            this.viewWidth = this.stretchBy.offsetWidth;
            this.viewHeight = this.stretchBy.offsetHeight;
        }

        // show and resize all background holders
        for(i = 0; i < this.holders.length; i++) {
            this.holders[i].style.display = 'block';
            this.resizeHolder(this.holders[i]);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
            this.resizeImage(this.images[i]);
        }
    }),10);
},
addHandlers: function() {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.bind(this.resizeAll), false);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange',  this.bind(this.resizeAll), false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onresize', this.bind(this.resizeAll));
    }
},
stretchFunctions: {
    window: {
        width: function() {
            return typeof window.innerWidth === 'number' ?  window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        },
        height: function() {
            return typeof window.innerHeight === 'number' ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }
    },
    page: {
        width: function() {
            return !document.body ? 0 : Math.max(
                Math.max(document.body.clientWidth,  document.documentElement.clientWidth),
                Math.max(document.body.offsetWidth, document.body.scrollWidth)
            );
        },
        height: function() {
            return !document.body ? 0 : Math.max(
                Math.max(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight),
                Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight,  document.body.scrollHeight)
            );
        }
    }
},
bind: function(fn, scope, args) {
    var newScope = scope || this;
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(newScope, args || arguments);
    }
}
}.init();
// clear inputs on focus
function initInputs() {
// replace options
var opt = {
    clearInputs: true,
    clearTextareas: true,
    clearPasswords: true
}
// collect all items
var inputs = [].concat(
    PlaceholderInput.convertToArray(document.getElementsByTagName('input')),
    PlaceholderInput.convertToArray(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'))
);
// apply placeholder class on inputs
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].className.indexOf('default') < 0) {
        var inputType = PlaceholderInput.getInputType(inputs[i]);
        if((opt.clearInputs && inputType === 'text') ||
            (opt.clearTextareas && inputType === 'textarea') || 
            (opt.clearPasswords && inputType === 'password')
        ) {
            new PlaceholderInput({
                element:inputs[i],
                wrapWithElement:false,
                showUntilTyping:false,
                getParentByClass:false,
                placeholderAttr:'value'
            });
        }
    }
}
}

// input type placeholder class
;(function(){
PlaceholderInput = function() {
    this.options = {
        element:null,
        showUntilTyping:false,
        wrapWithElement:false,
        getParentByClass:false,
        placeholderAttr:'value',
        inputFocusClass:'focus',
        inputActiveClass:'text-active',
        parentFocusClass:'parent-focus',
        parentActiveClass:'parent-active',
        labelFocusClass:'label-focus',
        labelActiveClass:'label-active',
        fakeElementClass:'input-placeholder-text'
    }
    this.init.apply(this,arguments);
}
PlaceholderInput.convertToArray = function(collection) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0, ref = arr.length = collection.length; i < ref; i++) {
     arr[i] = collection[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
PlaceholderInput.getInputType = function(input) {
    return (input.type ? input.type : input.tagName).toLowerCase();
}
PlaceholderInput.prototype = {
    init: function(opt) {
        this.setOptions(opt);
        if(this.element && this.element.PlaceholderInst) {
            this.element.PlaceholderInst.refreshClasses();
        } else {
            this.element.PlaceholderInst = this;
            if(this.elementType == 'text' || this.elementType ==  'password' || this.elementType == 'textarea') {
                this.initElements();
                this.attachEvents();
                this.refreshClasses();
            }
        }
    },
    setOptions: function(opt) {
        for(var p in opt) {
            if(opt.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                this.options[p] = opt[p];
            }
        }
        if(this.options.element) {
            this.element = this.options.element;
            this.elementType =  PlaceholderInput.getInputType(this.element);
            this.wrapWithElement = (this.elementType === 'password' || this.options.showUntilTyping ? true : this.options.wrapWithElement);
            this.setOrigValue( this.options.placeholderAttr == 'value' ? this.element.defaultValue : this.element.getAttribute(this.options.placeholderAttr) );
        }
    },
    setOrigValue: function(value) {
        this.origValue = value;
    },
    initElements: function() {
        // create fake element if needed
        if(this.wrapWithElement) {
            this.element.value = '';
            this.element.removeAttribute(this.options.placeholderAttr);
            this.fakeElement = document.createElement('span');
            this.fakeElement.className = this.options.fakeElementClass;
            this.fakeElement.innerHTML += this.origValue;
            this.fakeElement.style.color = getStyle(this.element, 'color');
            this.fakeElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            this.element.parentNode.insertBefore(this.fakeElement, this.element);
        }
        // get input label
        if(this.element.id) {
            this.labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
            for(var i = 0; i < this.labels.length; i++) {
                if(this.labels[i].htmlFor === this.element.id) {
                    this.labelFor = this.labels[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // get parent node (or parentNode by className)
        this.elementParent = this.element.parentNode;
        if(typeof this.options.getParentByClass === 'string') {
            var el = this.element;
            while(el.parentNode) {
                if(hasClass(el.parentNode,  this.options.getParentByClass)) {
                    this.elementParent = el.parentNode;
                    break;
                } else {
                    el = el.parentNode;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    attachEvents: function() {
        this.element.onfocus = bindScope(this.focusHandler, this);
        this.element.onblur = bindScope(this.blurHandler, this);
        if(this.options.showUntilTyping) {
            this.element.onkeydown = bindScope(this.typingHandler, this);
            this.element.onpaste = bindScope(this.typingHandler, this);
        }
        if(this.wrapWithElement) this.fakeElement.onclick = bindScope(this.focusSetter, this);
    },
    togglePlaceholderText: function(state) {
        if(this.wrapWithElement) {
            this.fakeElement.style.display = state ? '' : 'none';
        } else {
            this.element.value = state ? this.origValue : '';
        }
    },
    focusSetter: function() {
        this.element.focus();
    },
    focusHandler: function() {
        this.focused = true;
        if(!this.element.value.length || this.element.value === this.origValue) {
            if(!this.options.showUntilTyping) {
                this.togglePlaceholderText(false);
            }
        }
        this.refreshClasses();
    },
    blurHandler: function() {
        this.focused = false;
        if(!this.element.value.length || this.element.value === this.origValue) {
            this.togglePlaceholderText(true);
        }
        this.refreshClasses();
    },
    typingHandler: function() {
        setTimeout(bindScope(function(){
            if(this.element.value.length) {
                this.togglePlaceholderText(false);
                this.refreshClasses();
            }
        },this), 10);
    },
    refreshClasses: function() {
        this.textActive = this.focused || (this.element.value.length && this.element.value !== this.origValue);
        this.setStateClass(this.element, this.options.inputFocusClass,this.focused);
        this.setStateClass(this.elementParent, this.options.parentFocusClass,this.focused);
        this.setStateClass(this.labelFor, this.options.labelFocusClass,this.focused);
        this.setStateClass(this.element, this.options.inputActiveClass, this.textActive);
        this.setStateClass(this.elementParent, this.options.parentActiveClass, this.textActive);
        this.setStateClass(this.labelFor, this.options.labelActiveClass, this.textActive);
    },
    setStateClass: function(el,cls,state) {
        if(!el) return; else if(state) addClass(el,cls); else removeClass(el,cls);
    }
}

// utility functions
function hasClass(el,cls) {
    return el.className ? el.className.match(new  RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)')) : false;
}
function addClass(el,cls) {
    if (!hasClass(el,cls)) el.className += " "+cls;
}
function removeClass(el,cls) {
    if (hasClass(el,cls)) {el.className=el.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'),' ');}
}
function bindScope(f, scope) {
    return function() {return f.apply(scope, arguments)}
}
function getStyle(el, prop) {
    if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null)[prop];
    } else if (el.currentStyle) {
        return el.currentStyle[prop];
    } else {
        return el.style[prop];
    }
}
  }());

  if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", initInputs, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", initInputs);
 // init rounded corners
 function initRoundedCorners() {
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if(images[i].className.indexOf('rounded-corner-') != -1) {
        var radValue = parseInt(images[i].className.replace(/.*rounded-corner-(\d+).*/, '$1'),10);
        if(!isNaN(radValue)) {
            new ImgCorner({
                image: images[i],
                radius: radValue
            });
        }
    }
}
 }

 // DOM ready
 function domReady(handler){
var called = false
function ready() {
    if (called) return;
    called = true
    handler()
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", ready, false )
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
    if (document.documentElement.doScroll && window == window.top) {
        function tryScroll(){
            if (called) return
            if (!document.body) return
            try {
                document.documentElement.doScroll("left")
                ready()
            } catch(e) {
                setTimeout(tryScroll, 0)
            }
        }
        tryScroll()
    }
    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
        if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
            ready()
        }
    })
}
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('load', ready, false)
else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload', ready)
}

domReady(initRoundedCorners);



 // rounded image module
 ;(function(window){
// init VML for IE6, IE7, IE8
var IE = /(MSIE (6|7|8))/.test(navigator.userAgent);
if(IE) {
    var ns = 'rcr';
    if(document.namespaces && !document.namespaces[ns]) {
        // add VML namespace
        document.namespaces.add(ns,'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml','#default#VML'); 
        // create stylesheets
        var screenStyleSheet, printStyleSheet;
        screenStyleSheet = document.createElement('style');
        screenStyleSheet.setAttribute('media', 'screen');
        document.documentElement.firstChild.insertBefore(screenStyleSheet, document.documentElement.firstChild.firstChild);
        if (screenStyleSheet.styleSheet) {
            try {
                // add screen-media rule
                screenStyleSheet = screenStyleSheet.styleSheet;
                screenStyleSheet.addRule(ns + '\\:*', '{behavior:url(#default#VML); display:inline-block}');
                // add a print-media stylesheet
                printStyleSheet = document.createElement('style');
                printStyleSheet.setAttribute('media', 'print');
                document.documentElement.firstChild.insertBefore(printStyleSheet, screenStyleSheet);
                printStyleSheet = printStyleSheet.styleSheet;
                printStyleSheet.addRule(ns + '\\:*', '{display: none !important;}');
            } catch(e) {}
        }
    }
}

// browsers techniques support detection
var supportCanvas = !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
var supportBorderRadius = (function(){
    var cssAttributeNames = ['borderRadius','BorderRadius','MozBorderRadius','WebkitBorderRadius','OBorderRadius','KhtmlBorderRadius']; 
    for (var i = 0; i < cssAttributeNames.length; i++) {
        var attributeName = cssAttributeNames[i];
        if (document.documentElement.style[attributeName] !== undefined) {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}());

// rounded image class
ImgCorner = function() {
    this.options = {
        radius: 0,
        image: null,
        roundedClass: 'img-rounded'
    }
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
}
ImgCorner.prototype = {
    init: function(options) {
        for(var p in options) {
            if(options.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                this.options[p] = options[p];
            }
        }
        this.initImage();
    },
    initImage: function() {
        // create image to calculate dimensions
        if(this.options.image) {
            // check borders
            this.realImage = this.options.image;
            this.borderWidth = parseInt(this.getStyle(this.realImage, 'borderTopWidth')) || 0;
            this.borderColor = this.getStyle(this.realImage, 'borderTopColor') || '#333';

            this.tmpImage = new Image();
            this.tmpImage.onload = this.bind(function() {
                this.realWidth = this.tmpImage.width;
                this.realHeight = this.tmpImage.height;
                this.onImageComplete();
            },this);
            this.tmpImage.src = this.realImage.src;
        }
    },
    onImageComplete: function() {
        if(IE) {
            this.createVMLNode();
        } else {
            if(supportBorderRadius) {
                this.createCSS3Node();
            } else if(supportCanvas) {
                this.createCanvasNode();
            }
        }
    },
    createCanvasNode: function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'), ctx;
        canvas.width = this.realWidth + this.borderWidth*2;
        canvas.height = this.realHeight + this.borderWidth*2;
        if(typeof canvas.getContext === 'function') {
            // create path function
            var createPath = function(dc,x,y,w,h,r,bw) {
                var a = Math.PI/180;
                r -= bw;
                dc.beginPath();
                dc.moveTo(x+r,y);
                dc.lineTo(x+w-r,y);
                dc.arc(x+w-r,y+r,r,a*270,a*360,false);
                dc.lineTo(x+w,y+h-r);
                dc.arc(x+w-r,y+h-r,r,a*0,a*90,false);
                dc.lineTo(x+r,y+h);
                dc.arc(x+r,y+h-r,r,a*90,a*180,false);
                dc.lineTo(x,y+r);
                dc.arc(x+r,y+r,r,a*180,a*270,false); 
            }

            // create rounded path
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.save();
            createPath(ctx, this.borderWidth,this.borderWidth,this.realWidth,this.realHeight,this.options.radius, this.borderWidth);

            // draw border only if needed
            if(this.borderWidth) {
                ctx.strokeStyle = this.borderColor;
                ctx.lineWidth = this.borderWidth*2;
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            ctx.clip();
            ctx.drawImage(this.tmpImage,this.borderWidth,this.borderWidth);
            ctx.restore();

            // append canvas image
            this.realImage.style.display = 'none';
            this.realImage.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, this.realImage);
        }
    },
    createVMLNode: function() {
        var w = this.realWidth, h = this.realHeight, r = this.options.radius;
        var vmlBox = document.createElement('corner');
        var sh = document.createElement(ns + ':shape');
        var filler = document.createElement(ns + ':fill');
        vmlBox.style.cssText = 'width:'+this.realWidth+'px;height:'+this.realHeight+'px;margin:0;padding:0;border:0;';
        sh.appendChild(filler);
        sh.style.cssText = 'width:'+this.realWidth+'px;height:'+this.realHeight+'px;display:inline-block;';
        sh.path = 'm '+r+',0 l '+(w-r)+',0 qx '+w+','+r+' l '+w+','+(h-r)+' qy '+(w-r)+','+h+' l '+r+','+h+' qx 0,'+(h-r)+' l 0,'+r+' qy '+r+',0 e';
        sh.coordorigin = "-1 -1";
        sh.coordsize = w+' '+h;

        // draw border if needed
        if(this.borderWidth) {
            sh.strokecolor = this.borderColor;
            sh.strokeweight = this.borderWidth/2;
            sh.stroked = true;
        } else {
            sh.stroked = false;
        }

        filler.style.display = 'inline-block';
        filler.setAttribute('type', 'frame');
        filler.setAttribute('src', this.realImage.src);
        vmlBox.appendChild(sh);
        vmlBox.innerHTML = vmlBox.innerHTML;
        this.realImage.style.display = 'none';
        this.realImage.parentNode.insertBefore(vmlBox, this.realImage);
    },
    createCSS3Node: function() {
        var borderAttr = ['borderRadius', 'MozBorderRadius', 'WebkitBorderRadius', 'OBorderRadius']; 
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.style.width = this.realWidth+'px';
        span.style.height = this.realHeight+'px';
        span.style.display = 'inline-block';
        span.style.background = 'url('+this.realImage.src+')';
        span.style.overflow = 'hiddden';

        for(var i = 0; i < borderAttr.length; i++) {
            span.style[borderAttr[i]] = this.options.radius + 'px';
        }

        // draw border if needed
        if(this.borderWidth) {
            span.style.border = this.borderWidth+'px solid  '+this.borderColor;
        }

        this.realImage.style.border = '0';
        this.realImage.style.display = 'none';
        this.realImage.parentNode.insertBefore(span, this.realImage);
        span.appendChild(this.realImage);
        return span;
    },
    getStyle: function(el, prop) {
        if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
            return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null)[prop];
        } else if (el.currentStyle) {
            return el.currentStyle[prop];
        } else {
            return el.style[prop];
        }
    },
    bind: function(fn, scope, args) {
        return function() {
            return fn.apply(scope, args || arguments);
        }
    } 
}
  })(this);
 /*! HTML5 Shiv pre3.5 | @afarkas @jdalton @jon_neal @rem | MIT/GPL2 Licensed
  Uncompressed source: https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv  */
 ;(function(){
  /*@cc_on(function(a,b){function h(a,b){var c=a.createElement("p"),d=a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||a.documentElement;return c.innerHTML="x<style>"+b+"</style>",d.insertBefore(c.lastChild,d.firstChild)}function i(){var a=l.elements;return typeof a=="string"?a.split(" "):a}function j(a){var b={},c=a.createElement,f=a.createDocumentFragment,g=f();a.createElement=function(a){l.shivMethods||c(a);var f;return b[a]?f=b[a].cloneNode():e.test(a)?f=(b[a]=c(a)).cloneNode():f=c(a),f.canHaveChildren&&!d.test(a)?g.appendChild(f):f},a.createDocumentFragment=Function("h,f","return function(){var n=f.cloneNode(),c=n.createElement;h.shivMethods&&("+i().join().replace(/\w+/g,function(a){return b[a]=c(a),g.createElement(a),'c("'+a+'")'})+");return n}")(l,g)}function k(a){var b;return a.documentShived?a:(l.shivCSS&&!f&&(b=!!h(a,"article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}audio{display:none}canvas,video{display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1}[hidden]{display:none}audio[controls]{display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1}mark{background:#FF0;color:#000}")),g||(b=!j(a)),b&&(a.documentShived=b),a)}function p(a){var b,c=a.getElementsByTagName("*"),d=c.length,e=RegExp("^(?:"+i().join("|")+")$","i"),f=[];while(d--)b=c[d],e.test(b.nodeName)&&f.push(b.applyElement(q(b)));return f}function q(a){var b,c=a.attributes,d=c.length,e=a.ownerDocument.createElement(n+":"+a.nodeName);while(d--)b=c[d],b.specified&&e.setAttribute(b.nodeName,b.nodeValue);return e.style.cssText=a.style.cssText,e}function r(a){var b,c=a.split("{"),d=c.length,e=RegExp("(^|[\\s,>+~])("+i().join("|")+")(?=[[\\s,>+~#.:]|$)","gi"),f="$1"+n+"\\:$2";while(d--)b=c[d]=c[d].split("}"),b[b.length-1]=b[b.length-1].replace(e,f),c[d]=b.join("}");return c.join("{")}function s(a){var b=a.length;while(b--)a[b].removeNode()}function t(a){var b,c,d=a.namespaces,e=a.parentWindow;return!o||a.printShived?a:(typeof d[n]=="undefined"&&d.add(n),e.attachEvent("onbeforeprint",function(){var d,e,f,g=a.styleSheets,i=[],j=g.length,k=Array(j);while(j--)k[j]=g[j];while(f=k.pop())if(!f.disabled&&m.test(f.media)){for(d=f.imports,j=0,e=d.length;j<e;j++)k.push(d[j]);try{i.push(f.cssText)}catch(l){}}i=r(i.reverse().join("")),c=p(a),b=h(a,i)}),e.attachEvent("onafterprint",function(){s(c),b.removeNode(!0)}),a.printShived=!0,a)}var c=a.html5||{},d=/^<|^(?:button|form|map|select|textarea|object|iframe)$/i,e=/^<|^(?:a|b|button|code|div|fieldset|form|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|i|iframe|img|input|label|li|link|ol|option|p|param|q|script|select|span|strong|style|table|tbody|td|textarea|tfoot|th|thead|tr|ul)$/i,f,g;(function(){var c=b.createElement("a");c.innerHTML="<xyz></xyz>",f="hidden"in c,f&&typeof injectElementWithStyles=="function"&&injectElementWithStyles("#modernizr{}",function(b){b.hidden=!0,f=(a.getComputedStyle?getComputedStyle(b,null):b.currentStyle).display=="none"}),g=c.childNodes.length==1||function(){try{b.createElement("a")}catch(a){return!0}var c=b.createDocumentFragment();return typeof c.cloneNode=="undefined"||typeof c.createDocumentFragment=="undefined"||typeof c.createElement=="undefined"}()})();var l={elements:c.elements||"abbr article aside audio bdi canvas data datalist details figcaption figure footer header hgroup mark meter nav output progress section summary time video",shivCSS:c.shivCSS!==!1,shivMethods:c.shivMethods!==!1,type:"default",shivDocument:k};a.html5=l,k(b);var m=/^$|\b(?:all|print)\b/,n="html5shiv",o=!g&&function(){var c=b.documentElement;return typeof b.namespaces!="undefined"&&typeof b.parentWindow!="undefined"&&typeof c.applyElement!="undefined"&&typeof c.removeNode!="undefined"&&typeof a.attachEvent!="undefined"}();l.type+=" print",l.shivPrint=t,t(b)})(this,document);@*/
}());
```

Regards

Comment: Maybe you could trim your additional information down (just by 127 chrs) so we can fit this into the question. Otherwise we'll just keep seeing flags on this. Better still, why not put the large blob of source code on jsfiddle? Thanks.