# JSF update/re-render ui:repeat data with ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I've this search.xhtml page having some attributes in a form.
There's a search button which brings a list from the db through a method in the backing bean. 
The list, I'm using in ui:repeat. 
Now, when the user clicks the search button, i want the list and the data in the view(xhtml) to be ajax updated.

So far, i've tried this. My search.xhtml page

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/homepage-style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/profile.css" />
        <title>Shadi Bandhan | We find the best match for you</title>

        <script src="../jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){  
                // all the code goes here! including functions!!!  

                $('#loading').fadeOut();

                $('div#searchResults').hide();
                $('div#searchResults').fadeIn(3000);
                //                $('div#searchResults').fadeIn(3000);


                function callme(){
                    $('#loading').fadeIn(3000);
                    $('div#searchResults').fadeOut(1000);
                    $('div#searchResults').fadeIn(); 
                }
                function showLoading(){  
                    $('#loading')  
                    .css({visibility:"visible"})  
                    .css({opacity:"1"})  
                    .css({display:"block"})  
                    ;  
                }

            });


        </script>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <div id="header">
            <ui:insert name="header" >
                <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="main-content">
            <p:growl autoUpdate="true" />

            <div id="left-pane">

                <div id="profile-info-area">
                    <div id="profile-info">

                        <span>
                            <img class="profileImg" src="../#{myProfileManagedBean.profileImgPath}" width="185" height="200" />
                        </span>

                        <center>
                            <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Upload Photo" action="#{profileAlbumManagedBean.getUserAlbum}" styleClass="upload-photo-btn" />
                        </center>

                        <p:commandLink value="My Photos" action="#{profileAlbumManagedBean.getUserAlbum}" /> <br />
                        <a href="friends.xhtml">My Friends</a> <br />
                        <a href="planPackages.xhtml">My Packages</a> <br />
                        <p:commandLink value="Privacy Settings" action="#{myProfileManagedBean.getProfileSetting}" /> <br />
                        <a href="#">FAQs</a>

                    </div>

                    <div id="pesonal-attributes">

                        <h:form id="searchForm2">
                            <table width="190" height="200" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Age:</td>
                                    <td><select name="select" class="search-select" >
                                            <option>18-22</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Religion:</td>
                                    <td><select name="select2" class="search-select" >
                                            <option>Islam</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Cast:</td>
                                    <td><select name="select3" class="search-select" >
                                            <option>Malik</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Country:</td>
                                    <td><select name="select4" class="search-select" >
                                            <option>Pakistan</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>City:</td>
                                    <td><select name="select5" class="search-select" >
                                            <option>18-22</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Gender:</td>
                                    <td><select name="select6" class="search-select" >
                                            <option>18-22</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Education</td>
                                    <td><select name="select7" class="search-select" >
                                            <option>18-22</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Marital Status</td>
                                    <td><select name="select8" class="search-select" >
                                            <option>Single</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Interests</td>
                                    <td><select name="select9" class="search-select">
                                            <option>Reading</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Family</td>
                                    <td><select name="select10" class="search-select" >
                                            <option>Simple</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Occupation</td>
                                    <td><select name="select11" class="search-select" >
                                            <option>Doctor</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>

                                        <p:commandButton id="search" onclick="callme();" value="Search" actionListener="#{searchManagedBean.searchExactMatch2}" styleClass="p-search-btn" >

                                            <f:ajax render=":searchResultsForm" />
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>

                                        <p:commandButton value="Reset" styleClass="p-search-btn" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </h:form>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="home-main-area">

                    <div id="interests-expressions-wrapper">

                        <div id="interests-expressions-header">

                            <div id="search-heading">
                                Search Matches
                            </div>

                            <div id="m-search">

                                <div id="loading">
                                    <p>Please wait while we search</p><img src="../images/loading.gif" width="30" height="30" />
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div id="searchResults">

                            <h:form id="searchResultsForm">

                                <h:panelGroup>

                                    <ui:repeat id="userSearchResults" var="user" value="#{searchManagedBean.searchResults}">

                                        <center><img class="h-diff" src="../images/differentiator-profile.jpg" width="437" height="1" /></center>
                                        <div class="intExpression">
                                            <div id="senderImg">
                                                <img class="senderImg" src="../images/profile-pic.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
                                            </div>

                                            <div id="intExpression-area">

                                                <div id="senderName">
                                                    <p:commandLink id="senderNameLink" styleClass="senderName" value="#{user.profileFullname}" action="#{myProfileManagedBean.getOtherProfileInfo(userFriend.profileId)}"></p:commandLink>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="intExpression-body">
                                                    #{user.profileAge} <br />
                                                    #{user.profileReligion} <br />
                                                    #{user.profileLocation} <br />

                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </ui:repeat>
                                </h:panelGroup>

                                <p:blockUI block="userSearchResults" trigger=":searchForm2:search" /> 



                            </h:form>

                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="right-pane">
                <ui:insert name="right-pane" >
                    <ui:include src="right-pane.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <ui:insert name="footer" >
                <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Searched for hours on SO,
but just couldn't figure out how to do it.
Using JSF 2.0, Primefaces 3.3, Hibernate 3

Thanks

Comment: Don't load jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112058/how-to-use-jquery-and-jquery-plugins-with-primefaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing primefaces and core JSF approaches. Try to stick to primefaces to begin with and replace

```
<p:commandButton id="search" onclick="callme();" value="Search" actionListener="#{searchManagedBean.searchExactMatch2}" styleClass="p-search-btn" >
  <f:ajax render=":searchResultsForm" />
</p:commandButton>
```

with

```
<p:commandButton id="search" onclick="callme();return true;" value="Search" actionListener="#{searchManagedBean.searchExactMatch2}" styleClass="p-search-btn" update=":searchResultsForm"/>
```

I have added return true to onclick to make sure the event won't be ignored and used `update` attribute instead of `f:ajax` tag. I'm not 100% sure about the colon in primefaces `update`, you may also try without it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace *ui:repeat* by *c:forEach*

Old:

```
<ui:repeat id="userSearchResults" var="user" value="#{searchManagedBean.searchResults}">
..
</ui:repeat>
```

New:

```
<c:forEach id="userSearchResults" var="user" items="#{searchManagedBean.searchResults}" >
..
</c:forEach>
```

Namespace definition for *c:forEach*:

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

Comment: please do not ever recommend c:forEach for jsf pages. It doesn't cooperate with its lifecycle.

Comment: Article about c:forEach vs ui:repeat: http://www.ninthavenue.com.au/blog/c:foreach-vs-ui:repeat-in-facelets - If you know what you are doing, you can use it. Anyhow: property id is useless, don't use it for forEach.