# Problems having Jquery and Primefaces

Tags: jquery-ui, primefaces

I having problems putting a buttonset with Primefaces.
I saw some other posts
[How to use jQuery and jQuery plugins with PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112058/how-to-use-jquery-with-primefaces)
 with similiar issues and didn´t get any result.

heres the a code sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <f:view locale="#{templateManager.userLocale}">
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>#{msgs['report.title']}</title>
            <h:outputStylesheet name="ssl-common.css" library="css"/>
            <h:outputStylesheet name="final.css" library="css"/>
            <link href="#{resource['img:favicon.ico']}" rel="icon"/>
            <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />

        </h:head>
        <body id="reportList">
            <ui:include src="../WEB-INF/header.xhtml" />
            <section>
                <h:form prependId="false">
                    <nav>
                        <div id="actionBar">
                            <div class="wraper">
                                <hgroup>
                                    <h1>#{msgs['report.title']}</h1>
                                </hgroup>
                                <div id="subMenu" style="padding: 10px">

                                    <script>
                                        $(function() {
                                            $("#radio").buttonset();
                                        });
                                    </script>

                                    <div id="radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>

       (...)

            <h:outputScript library="js" name="common.js"/>
            <h:outputScript library="js" name="script.js"/>
            <h:outputScript library="js" name="primefacesLocalePT-PT.js" />
            <!--<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-ui-1.8.2.js" />-->
            <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;language=#{templateManager.userLocale}" type="text/javascript"/>
        </body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

With this code I receive the error:

TypeError: $(...).buttonset is not a function
[Break On This Error]

$("#radio").buttonset();

does anybody had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery UI, too. Right now the script tag for that is commented out.

Comment: Yes it is. But correct me if i am wrong, doesn´t primefaces has this embedded feature?

Comment: @RuiBatalha yes but you also included jQuery.js manually. Primefaces will automatically include all necessary jQuery parts, but you must have at least one Primefaces component on page, which is not case here.

Comment: @partlov Sorry I erased the part of the code that used primefaces :S
However I think something odd.Searching in my project in the primefaces jar I don´t see the resource button (META-INF.resources.primefaces...).
I am getting confused. Primefaces doesn´t use jQuery-ui buttons?