# jQuery errors with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using jQuery in jsf pages and I have an issue with IE

```
Message : '$' is undefined
Line : 1
character : 1
Code : 0
URI : .............../js/test.js.jsf
```

the script begin with  `$.extend($.expr[':'], {`

Comment: Could you translate the errors into English? (Or change your browser settings to English and recreate the error?)

Comment: You seem not to have jquery. In case you have you will be able to log `$.fn.jquery`. The fact is others browsers than IE have a global `$` variable but if you don't load jquery `$` is not jquery

Comment: That message is telling you `$` is undefined.  Make sure you include jQuery.

Comment: In fact, '$' is undefined. It looks like you haven't included jquery on your page properly: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery link"></script>`

Comment: I'm using jquery as well and it's work in other navigators, I'm reusing primefaces Jquery with jsf pages <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />

Comment: messages are clear without translating in english, first char in the specified line means '$' is undefined

Comment: just to be sure, can you check if the error still there with: `jQuery( document ) ...` ? the `$` shortcut can be disabled.

Comment: same issue using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FrozenFlame thank you for your help, you are right but I don't know why `<h:outputScript..` is imported twice when it is used in multiple referenced `<iframe>`

in my case my main jsf page call two iframe.

```
<iframe name="test1" src="test1.jsf" />
<iframe name="test2" src="test2.jsf" />
```

both iframe and the main page include the same js file :

```
<h:outputScript name="js/test.js" />
```

my problem is solved by deleting unused js in the two iframe

thanx

Answer (score 1):

normaly if you use the jsf import
 `<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />` , jsf garantees that the script is only imported one time , 
IE isn't tolerent to duplicate script import .

take a look at this link : 
[how to use jquery with primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112058/how-to-use-jquery-with-primefaces)