# jQuery undefined during primefaces upgrade

Tags: primefaces

Upgraded primefaces from 5.3.6 to 6.2. Primefaces extn to 3.1.0 to 6.2 in my application.Using IE11 browser.Getting below error in my application. Why jquery shows up undefined when primefaces 6.2 has jquery 3.2.1.

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
jquery.js.xhtml (3,147)

The value of the property 'jQuery' is null or undefined, not a Function object for below code
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
-----
---
---
}
```

In xhtml files added below lines in pages which needs to use jquery

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head"/>
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" target="head" />
```

Comment: 1) Did you use a search engine to find causes for this? 2) why did you add it manually to a page? 3) Tried doing a clean build?

Comment: Do not include your own Jquery. PF includes its own version for you.

Comment: @Melloware I included prime faces one in pages where I need Jquery .I didn't include mine.

Comment: @Kukeltje Developer tool console shows these errors.Done clean build still same error.Added primefaces jquery where I need jQuery to use in pages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508564/how-to-solve-a-conflict-with-primefaces-jquery jquery is automatically added to the page when there is a primefaces component on it